# Rescaling XPM image

Tags: image, scale

ALL,

I have an XPM image with the size of 10x10. What I would like to do is to scale it so that the size becomes 16x16.

Does anybody knows how I can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **ImageMagick**, which is installed on most Linux distros, and is available for macOS and Windows:

```
convert small.xpm -scale 16x16 bigger.xpm
```